# Have to transform some bunch of csv in req format and store it in some other location with same name

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have some input CSV files INPUT_FILE:

```
A_B_C_NFM001_20150729.csv
A_B_C_NFM002_20150729.csv
A_B_C_NFM003_20150730.csv
```

I want an output file also with the same name as the input after performing the below transformation on the input file. I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/path/transformed_dir
var=echo /home/dbadmin/Indus_Project/PING_STATUS/A_B_C_*.csv | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)'
arr=($var)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i } NR>1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "," sn[i] "," $i }' A_B_C__$i.csv > $TARGET/A_B_C__$i.csv
done
```

But it is giving the output file as `A_B_C_*_.csv`

Answer (score -1):

The declaration of the array should look as follows:

```
declare -a arr=$( $(echo /home/dbadmin/Indus_Project/PING_STATUS/A_B_C_*.csv) | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)' )
```

in your original command declaration of `var` should not even work and the detour for declaring the array `arr` via `var` is not necessary.

Comment: `arr` is still a single string. Arrays are created using `arr=( ... )`.  In this case, `arr=( /home/dbadmin/Indus_Project/PING_STATUS/A_B_C_*.csv )`.